# LINQ-to-SQL: Searching against a CSV

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, generics

I'm using LINQtoSQL and I want to return a list of matching records for a CSV contains a list of IDs to match. The following code is my starting point, having turned a CSV string in a string array, then into a generic list (which I thought LINQ would like) - but it doesn't:

**Error**

```
Error 22 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' C:\Documents and Settings\....\Search.cs 41 42 C:\...\
```

**Code**

```
    DataContext db = new DataContext();

    List<int> geographyList = new List<int>( Convert.ToInt32(geography.Split(',')) );

        var geographyMatches = from cg in db.ContactGeographies
                               where cg.GeographyId == geographyList
                               select new { cg.ContactId };
```

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var geographyMatches = from cg in db.ContactGeographies
                               where geographyList.Contains(cg.GeographyId)
                               select new { cg.ContactId };
```

Comment: This does the trick - this syntax seems odd to me, but I look at LINQ strange SQL eyes which it blinding me to these type of approaches

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, in `where cg.GeographyId == geographyList` you're trying to compare `int` to a `List<int>`. They're totally different types. I think you want to do `geographyList.Contains(cg.GeographyId)` or some other operation like that.